# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am looking to show that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)^k = 0. $$
In my application, $c = (e+1)/2 \approx 1.85914\ldots$. I have been looking all over the place, but I can't seem to find a closed form expression or good upper bound for the sum.

The obvious estimation
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(c\right)^k \leq \left(1+c\right)^n $$
won't do the trick, since $1+c=1+(1+e)/2 > e$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simple Approximation with Bernoulli's Inequalty**

Using Bernoulli's Inequality, we see that
$$
e^{-k}\le\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{n-k}\le e^{-k(1-k/n)}\tag{1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{e^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)^k
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{e^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{c(n-k)}{n}\right)^{n-k}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{e^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}c^{n-k}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{n-k}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac ce\right)^{n-k}\left[\frac1{e^2},\frac1{e^{2-k/n}}\right]^k\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)$ says that the limit is infinity if $c\gt e-\frac1e=2.3504023872876029138$.

The Central Limit Theorem says that as $n\to\infty$, the main contribution to
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k\tag{3}
$$
occurs within a $O\left(n^{-\frac12+\epsilon}\right)$ neighborhood of $\frac kn=\frac{y}{x+y}$. If we abbreviate $\frac kn=\alpha$, we get that the limit is $0$ if $c\lt e-\frac1{e^{1-\alpha}}$ where the Central Limit Theorem gives $\frac1\alpha-1=ce^{1-\alpha}$. Solving for $\alpha$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1\alpha-1\right)e^{\alpha-1}
&=e-e^{\alpha-1}\\
&\Downarrow\\
\alpha
&=-\mathrm{W}\left(-e^{-2}\right)\\
&=0.15859433956303936215\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$ yields that the limit is $0$ if $c\lt2.287177717128371900838$.

Since $\frac{e+1}2\lt2.287177717128371900838$, when $c$ is close to $\frac{e+1}{2}$, the limit is $0$.

This simple argument cannot tell what happens for
$$
2.287177717128371900838\lt c\lt2.3504023872876029138\tag{5}
$$

---

**More Precision with Laplace's Method**

For more precision, [Laplace's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) can be adapted to handle the sum
$$
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)^k\tag{6}
$$
In Laplace's Method, the integral is
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{s(x_\text{max})}}f(x_\text{max})\tag{7}
$$
where $s(x)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\log(f(x))$ and $f'(x_\text{max})=0$.

---

The first difference of $\log\binom{n}{k}$ is $\log\left(\frac{n-k}{k+1}\right)$. The derivative of $k\log\left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)$ is $1+\log\left(\frac{ck}{n}\right)$. Thus, we will approximate the first derivative of the log of the summand by
$$
\log\left(\frac{ce(n-k)}{n}\right)=\log(ce(1-\alpha))\tag{8}
$$
where $\alpha=\frac kn$. Thus, the maximum of the integrand is when 
$$
ce(1-\alpha)=1\tag{9}
$$
The negative of the second derivative of the log of the summand at the maximum is then
$$
\frac1{n-k}=\frac1{n(1-\alpha)}=\frac{ce}{n}\tag{10}
$$
Computing the value of the summand at its maximum using Stirling's formula:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{k(n-k)}}\frac{n^n}{k^k(n-k)^{n-k}}\frac{c^kk^k}{n^ke^n}\tag{11}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n\alpha(1-\alpha)}}\left(\frac{c^\alpha}{e(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}}\right)^n\tag{12}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n\alpha(1-\alpha)}}\left(ce^{-\alpha}\right)^n\tag{13}\\
&=\frac{ce}{\sqrt{2\pi n(ce-1)}}\left(\frac cee^{\large\frac1{ce}}\right)^n\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(7)$, $(10)$, and $(14)$, we get the sum in $(6)$ to be asymptotic to
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{ce}{ce-1}}\left(\frac cee^{\large\frac1{ce}}\right)^n\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Formula $(15)$ indicates that the breakpoint in $c$ between the limit being $0$ and being $\infty$ is when $\frac cee^{\large\frac1{ce}}=1$; that is,
$$
\begin{align}
c
&=-\frac1{e\mathrm{W}\left(-e^{-2}\right)}\\[6pt]
&\doteq2.3196252917035202431\tag{16}
\end{align}
$$
Note that the $c$ given in $(16)$ is almost in the middle of the range given in $(5)$. When $c$ is equal to the value in $(16)$, we get
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ce}{ce-1}}=1.0901776779197391224\tag{17}
$$
Using Mathematica 8, computing the sum in $(6)$ for the $c$ given in $(16)$ and $n=100000$ yields $1.090178422502261$; very close to $(17)$.

---

For $c=\frac{e+1}{2}$, approximation $(15)$ says that the sum is asymptotic to
$$
1.1165527750632721\times0.8335934600537050^n\tag{18}
$$
For $n=500$, $(18)$ gives $3.34987509422\times10^{-40}$, whereas actual computation yields $3.35051202913\times10^{-40}$, an error of less than $0.02\%$.

Comment: I was also trying similar approach, so I am curious how you treated the cumbersome bound $e^{k^{2}/n}$, especially when $k \approx n$.

Comment: (-1) for ignoring the $e^{k^2/n}$ (which certainly *cannot* be treated as a constant) leading to a wrong result, and for ignoring the fact that your asymptotics are off. Just plug in some largish value of $n$ and you will see that what you claim is asymptotically equivalent to the sum is not. (But of course if you had read my answer you would have known.)

Comment: @TMM: thanks for your concern. However after sos440's comment, I was looking more closely, and I found a more conservative bounding $c$. However, my numerical investigation with $n=10000$ showed a break close to $e-1/e$, so I tried to see if I could get closer to that. Unfortunately, I am out right now and I can barely post a comment on my phone, much less post any better estimates.

Comment: @sos440: Yes, I see that the error term can not be ignored. I have worked the afternoon on fixing this up. I will post the corrected version in a while.

Comment: If my analysis is correct, the break is at $\approx 2.32$ which is slightly smaller than $e - 1/e \approx 2.35$.

Comment: @TMM: that falls within my range of $2.287$ and $2.350$.

Comment: It's funny how you also have $W(-1/e^2)$ in your answer but you still have a different solution.

Comment: Less funny is how you get twice as many upvotes for a less precise solution. Maybe it's because you have a higher "reputation", maybe it's because readers are ignorant to this difference. In any case, my efforts are clearly wasted here; apparently getting it right is not important.

Comment: @TMM: I agree. To make things better, I have added an approach using Laplace's Method, and gotten a more accurate answer.

Comment: @robjohn That does not change the fact that previous upvotes did not reflect the quality of the approximation. Only now is your answer as accurate as mine, but still I think my answer is much simpler/cleaner than yours. (In the end you also resort to Stirling, and what you are doing with "Laplace's method" is just a very complicated way of taking derivatives, setting it equal to $0$, and approximating the whole sum by the value at its maximum.)

Comment: But like I said, apparently clarity and accuracy matter less than previous reputation and ignorant users who just randomly vote for answers without actually looking at the details. The best way to get votes is just to post a short and elegant wrong proof; not a somewhat longer, *correct* proof. Who needs correctness on a mathematics site anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I was also working with the inequality

$$ \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{n-k} \leq \exp \left( -k + \tfrac{k^{2}}{n} \right) = \exp\left\{ -n \cdot \tfrac{k}{n} \left( 1 - \tfrac{k}{n} \right) \right\}.$$

Now note that $q(x) = x(1-x)$ satisfies $q(1-x) = q(x)$ and $q(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}x $ on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$. Then we get

$$ 0 \leq k \leq \tfrac{1}{2}n \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \exp\left\{ -n \cdot \tfrac{k}{n} \left( 1 - \tfrac{k}{n} \right) \right\} = e^{-nq(k/n)} \leq e^{-k/2}. \tag{*} $$

To utilize this bound, we divide the sum into two part:

\begin{align*}
S_{n} := 
e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^{k} c^{k}
&= e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^{n-k} c^{n-k} \\
&\leq e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} e^{-nq(k/n)} \\
&\leq e^{-n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} e^{-nq(k/n)} + e^{-n} \sum_{\frac{n}{2} \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} e^{-nq(k/n)} \\
&= (c/e)^{n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} c^{-k} e^{-nq(k/n)} + e^{-n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} c^{k} e^{-nq(k/n)}.
\end{align*}

Here, in the last line, we applied the change of index $k \mapsto n-k$. Then we can use $\text{(*)}$ and we get the following crude bound:

\begin{align*}
S_{n}
&\leq (c/e)^{n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{1}{c\sqrt{e}} \right)^{k} + e^{-n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{c}{\sqrt{e}} \right)^{k} \\
&\leq \left\{ \frac{c}{e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{c\sqrt{e}} \right) \right\}^{n} + \left\{ \frac{1}{e} \left( 1 + \frac{c}{\sqrt{e}} \right) \right\}^{n}.
\end{align*}

Now note that $c > 0$ satisfies the following condition

$$ \frac{c}{e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{c\sqrt{e}} \right) < 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{e} \left( 1 + \frac{c}{\sqrt{e}} \right) < 1
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad c < e - \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} \simeq 2.111751169. $$

Since your $c$ is less than $2$, the claim follows.

---

A slightly generally, you can introduce a parameter $\delta \in (0, 1)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cl}
0 \leq k \leq \delta n
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left( 1 - \tfrac{k}{n} \right)^{n-k} \leq e^{-(1-\delta)k}, \\
0 \leq k \leq (1-\delta) n
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left( 1 - \tfrac{k}{n} \right)^{n-k} \leq e^{-\delta k}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

and our estimation is refined as

$$ S_{n} \leq \left( \frac{c}{e} + \frac{1}{e^{2-\delta}} \right)^{n} + \left( \frac{1}{e} + \frac{c}{e^{1+\delta}} \right)^{n}. $$

For both ratios to be less than 1, we must have $c < \min\{ e - e^{\delta-1}. e^{\delta}(e - 1) \}$. Maximizing this bound gives

$$ e^{\delta} = \frac{1 + e^{-1}}{1 + e^{-3}}, $$

Therefore

$$ c < \frac{e^{2}(e^{2} - 1)}{e^{3} + 1}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad S_{n} \leq \left( \frac{c}{e} + \frac{1}{e^{2}-e+1} \right)^{n} + \left( \frac{1}{e} + \frac{e^{2}-e+1}{e^{3}} c \right)^{n}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0. $$

Comment: (+1) for being very precise, and for finding a bound on $c$. In the last equation I think you made a typo though, you probably wanted to write $c < e - \frac{1}{\sqrt e}$. I've also updated my answer with a bound for $c$.

Comment: @TMM, Oh, thank you! I fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

To get an idea of the asymptotics, try using Stirling's approximation on the binomial coefficients:

$$\begin{align}\ln \left[{n \choose k} \left(\frac{c k}{n}\right)^k\right] &\sim \left[n \ln n - k \ln k - (n - k) \ln(n - k)\right] + \left[k \ln c + k \ln k - k \ln n\right] 
\\
&\sim (n-k) \ln\left(\frac{n}{n - k}\right) + k \ln c. \tag{1}\end{align}$$

Now, to see where the main "weight" of the summation is, i.e., for which values of $k$ the summands are the biggest, we just take the derivative with respect to $k$, set it equal to $0$, and solve for $k$:

$$1 + \ln \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right) + \ln c = 0 \implies k = \left(1 - \frac{1}{ce}\right)n$$

Plugging this value of $k$ into $(1)$, we get that for this value of $k$ the summand becomes

$${n \choose k} \left(\frac{c k}{n}\right)^k \sim \exp\left(\left(\ln c + \frac{1}{e c}\right)n\right).$$

So for large $n$, the whole argument of the limit (including the term $e^n$) scales as

$$\exp\left(\left(\ln c + \frac{1}{e c} - 1\right) n\right).$$

Filling in $c = (e + 1)/2$ we get a negative exponent guaranteeing convergence of the order $e^{-0.182009 n} = 2^{-0.26258\dots n}$. We can verify these results numerically, e.g., for $n = 500$ the exact value is $3.35051\ldots \cdot 10^{-40}$ while the asymptotic approximation gives us $3.00019\ldots \cdot 10^{-40}$. The order of magnitute is exactly right, and only the constant is slightly off by about $10\%$.

---

If you would also like to know for which values of $c$ you get convergence, you just have to find out when the exponent is negative:

$$\ln c + \frac{1}{e c} - 1 < 0 \iff c(1 - \ln c) < \frac{1}{e}.$$

Substituting $c = e \cdot d$ will make the $1$ on the left hand side disappear:

$$d \ln d > \frac{-1}{e^2}.$$

This cannot be solved with elementary functions, but using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) we get

$$d < e^{W(-1/e^2)} \implies c < e^{1 + W(-1/e^2)} = 2.31963\ldots.$$

Comment: The most elegant form for the constant $-0.26\dots$ I can find is $$\frac{2}{e(1+e) \ln 2} - \log_2\left(\frac{2e}{1+e}\right) = \frac{1}{e c \ln 2} - \log_2\left(\frac{e}{c}\right) = -0.26258\dots$$

Comment: Thanks! This looks really nice. I am not that familiar with estimates where we identify the center of mass of the sum. In particular, I have no feel for the ''errors'' you are getting with this method. I am currently working on the proof and I will also post it here. It looks like my ''direct'' approach gives a convergence with $2^{-0.204433n}$, which is slightly weaker than your $2^{-0.26258n}$.

Comment: @Timomue Like I said, for $n = 500$, the estimate is only $10\%$ off on an answer of the order $10^{-40}$, which is quite amazing. (For $n = 500$, your constant gives an estimate of $1.69 \cdot 10^{-31}$, which is almost a factor $10^{10}$ too high...)

Comment: @Timomue As for the "errors" you are getting, I've added a bit, showing that the errors are really small if you only focus on the highest mass. On the left hand side you can probably even replace the $o(n)$ in the exponent by $O(1)$ and in the right hand side by $O(\log n)$, if you want to be precise.

Comment: @TMM: I think the $10\%$ error might be due to the factor of $1.11655$ that falls out of my second approach using Laplace's Method for $c=\frac{e+1}{2}$.

Comment: @robjohn The $10\%$ comes from using more terms from Stirling's approximation, it has little to do with Laplace's method. A more precise version of Stirling gives an extra term $\ln \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \pi k(n-k)}}$ in $(1)$.

Comment: @TMM: for numbers as big as we are dealing with, further terms in Stirling's approximation will not help much. I computed the value for $c=\frac{e+1}{2}$ and $n=500$, and my asymptotic approximation yields $3.349875\times10^{-40}$ which has an error of $0.02\%$ instead of $11\%$.

Comment: @TMM: yes, I include that term in my appoximation. If that is left out, the approximation would be off by a much larger ratio.

Comment: @TMM: the factor of $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi k(n-k)}}$ is almost cancelled by the $\sqrt{2\pi(n-k)}$ from Laplace, which accounts for the factor of $\sqrt{\frac{ce}{ce-1}}$. It seems that leaving out these two factors gives the answer to within that factor.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\dbinom{n}{k} \le \left(\dfrac{e\,n}{k}\right)^k$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \le \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{e\,n}{k}\right)^k \left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k = \sum_{k=1}^n (e\,c)^k = \frac{(e\,c)^{n+1}-1}{e\,c-1}$$

Comment: I see. This is indeed an interesting bound. Unfortunately, it is larger than $(1+c)^n$, which makes it infeasible in my application.

Comment: How big is $c$ in your application?

Comment: $c = (e+1)/2 = 1.85914...$. I am still trying to reduce it a bit, but this is it so far.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate the sum , we first consider even $n$ and note the following:

- $c = \frac{(1+e)}{2} \approx 1.85914\dots < e$, and therefore, the last term of the sum for $k=n$ can be ignored as $\binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{c}{e}\right)^n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
- $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$, and therefore, both terms $\binom{n}{k}\left(c \frac{k}{n}\right)^k$ and $\binom{n}{k}\left(c \frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$ have the same binomial coefficient in the sum.
- The idea is to estimate the sum of both terms by an exponential function of the form $c \mapsto e^{m k + b}$, where $m$ and $b$ depend only on $n$ and $c$.
- Indeed, the log of the sum, the function $k \mapsto \log\left( \left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k + \left(c\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k} \right)$, is strictly convex and on the interval $\left[1,\frac{n}{2}\right]$ it is upper-bounded by the linear function
  $$ f(k) = \left(\frac{\log(4)}{n}-\log(2c)\right) k + n \log(c).$$
- Thus, $$\binom{n}{k}\left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k + \binom{n}{n-k}\left(c\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k} \leq \binom{n}{k} e^{f(k)}.$$

We can bound the sum by 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{e^n} \sum_{k=1}^{ \frac{n}{2} } \binom{n}{k} e^{f(k)} & = & \frac{1}{e^n} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{k} 4^{\frac{k}{n}} c^n \left(\frac{1}{2c}\right)^k \\
& \leq &  4\frac{c^n \left(1+ \frac{1}{2c}\right)^n}{e^n} \\
& = & 4\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2} + c}{e}\right)^n  \approx 4\left(\frac{2.35914}{e}\right)^n.
\end{eqnarray}
Since $2.35914 < e$, we get exponential convergence to $0$.

For odd $n$ the argument is essentially the same, except that we need to also consider the central term (for $k = \frac{n}{2}+1$) separately.
\begin{eqnarray}
\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+1} \left(c \frac{\frac{n}{2}+1}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+1} & \leq & 2^n  \left( \sqrt{c \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)^n \cdot c \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right) \\
& = & \left( \sqrt{c \left(2 + \frac{4}{n}\right)}\right)^n \cdot c \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
With $\sqrt{c \left(2 + \frac{4}{n}\right)} \approx 1.92828 < e$, the result follows for odd $n$ as well.

**Note on generality:**

So basically, if you want to estimate the asymptotics of 
$$ \frac{1}{x^n} \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(c\frac{k}{n}\right)^k, $$
the limit is guaranteed to be $0$ as long as $c \in [0,x-0.5)$.